# Check if first value is different to second via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'd like to check if the first value I get of an AJAX call is bigger than the next ones. Somehow I can't figure out how to do it. Every 5 seconds I check the value of followers.

```js
let callFollowers = () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      access_token: token
    },
    success: (result) => {
      let followers = result.data.counts.followed_by,
        counter = document.querySelector('#counter');
      let splitToDigits = (followers) => {
        return [...followers + ''].map(Number);
      };
      counter.innerHTML = '';
      for (let i = 0; i < splitToDigits(followers).length; i++) {
        let appendChild = document.createElement('span');
        appendChild.innerHTML = splitToDigits(followers)[i];
        counter.appendChild(appendChild);
      }
      console.log(followers);
    }
  })
};

callFollowers();
window.setInterval(callFollowers, 5000);
```

Comment: Place the value in a variable defined outside of the `success` handler in each call. Compare the new value to the old one and perform whatever action you need. Finally, update the value to that of the current request.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I can't use Websockets, because I'm only allowed to call the function a few times per hour. Otherwise instagram's API won't give back any JSON.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed the fact you were calling Instagram.

Comment: As an alternative to a variable, you could also use `$("#counter").data("count)` and store with `$("#counter").data("count", count);`  (not clear from your code exactly which is the count).

Comment: Could one of you add your comment as an answer so I can give it a checkmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the value in a variable defined outside of the success handler in each call. Compare the new value to the old one and perform whatever action you need. Finally, update the value to that of the current request.

Thanks @Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Create hidden input tag (Variable) on that page and store first value of ajax
Like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="result_store" id="result_store">
```

compare that value to second ajax result